# How to add Dynamic UIlabel in the middle of the View Controller?

Tags: ios7, uilabel

I'm new to I iPhone development. Here I'm doing an web service application in which I'm displaying  company details with the help of labels. Now while showing address of the company i'm stuck with a problem.

Company is having more than one locations. How to add address labels dynamically and push my below content down the view. Here i'm getting all the data from server.

Please guide me on this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please consider updating your question to include the code you've written, what you are seeing, and what you're expecting to see differently.

Comment: i m not having enough reputation to add image of my View to show clearly

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to put your labels in a table view and increase the number of cells as the location number increases. Put all the below content in the last cell as anew view. I am not sure what all contents you are having below. This one is possible. You may try.